# Web service vs client directly accessing remote db

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, wcf

What are cons and pros of web service vs direct client-sql server communication?

From my understanding:

Pros:

- If web service is installed on same computer as remote db then there is no need to open sql server port so that client can access to remote db. If web service is on another computer then port needs to be open for web service to access remote db.
- If someone manages to get a hold of user:pass he only can do operations on db that web service exposes, not all operations on entire db.

Cons:

- More work for programmer
- Slower

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that if you go with a Web Service/Rest Api you are centralizing the Business Layer where if there is a bug or a change you can control it very easily with no need of client upgrades.

I will only recommend you to go with direct db access only if you have a small number of clients, over a local network with too few updates to the business logic (aka simple app).

Comment: I slightly disagree with the second part.. also there are plenty of cases where thin clients use a mixture of both Web Services and Client side Dataccess Clients.. such as MySql, SQLite, Sql Server and Oracle DB

Comment: Yes app will be small, not sure if over local network. But you can achieve that you don't need to do client updates on bugs by calling stored procedures from clients. You modify stored procedures on server, which is centralized to all clients.